# More specific shape in Raphael (like rhombus)

Tags: raphael

Is there any easy way to create a shape like a rhombus in [raphael](/questions/tagged/raphael)? I suppose there's no command like:

```
var paper = new Raphael(document.getElementById('canvas_container'), 600, 600);
var rhombus = paper.rhombus(...);
```

Maybe there's an easier way than drawing path. Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing like `paper.rhombus` in Raphael. But you are free to extend the Raphael, so that you get rhombus method, as you have asked.

I have created small [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pLLt9/) for drawing the rhombus, in the same way you would like.

sample code from the fiddle.

```
    r.rhombus({
        cx:300,
        cy:300,
        side:15
    });

    // a rhombus rotated around its center.
    r.rhombus({
        cx:600,
        cy:300,
        side:15,
        angle:45
    }).attr({
        'stroke-width' :2
    })
```

Variable explanation:

```
cx - center x position
cy - center y position,
side - length of side of the rhombus.
angle - the angle through which the rhombus will be around its center (cx,cy)
```

learned much about rhombus :-)

Comment: Thank for the answer! I think have to get to know Javascript much more. :)

Answer (score 1):

I found it troublesome to use angle, because it also rotates the coordinate system for this object. When translating it later to the right for example, it will move diagonally to the southeast.
I used a path for a rhombus, the code was fairly short:

```
this.rhombus = this.paper.path("M 100 100 l30 -30 l30 30 l-30 30 l-30 -30");
```

M: move the "pen" to these coordinates
l: draw a line to a point relative to here, so 30 to the right and 30 up
and so on.